# Tikz Picture Behind Text on Page

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays, pgflayers

I thought I'd seen an answer to this a while ago, but I can't find it now.

I have a document with some variable text that I want to draw a TikZ picture behind based somewhat on a dimensions of the text.

I know I can use TikZ's `opacity` parameter to achieve the effect I want, but I really don't like this approach.

So, here's my attempt using layers.  I thought I understood this, but obviously I'm getting something wrong.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{2in}
\tikz[remember picture] \coordinate (A);%%
  Hello world
\tikz[remember picture] \coordinate (B);%%

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \coordinate (nA) at ([yshift=14pt]A)  ;
    \coordinate (sB) at ([yshift=-14pt]B);
    \draw (nA) -- (sB);
    \draw[fill=orange!80] (nA) rectangle (sB);
    %% ----------------------------------------------------
    %% I know this next line kind of achieves what I want.  
    %% I just prefer not to do it this way.                 
    %% ----------------------------------------------------
    % \draw[fill=orange,opacity=0.80] (nA) rectangle (sB);  
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

I tried moving the `tikzpicture` to the top of the document, but then the coordinates `A` and `B` haven't been defined yet.  I thought that should work on a second run.  I figured the `remember picture` aspect would record the nodes.  But this just failed.

Comment: The `pgfonlayer` mechanism does not give you access to the background of the page, but to the background of the `tikzpicture` it lies in. You do need to move `tikzpicture` to the beginning of the document; and then you test if (A) and (B) exists.

Comment: IIRC `tikzmark` is designed for this purpose (remembering coordinates across compilations).

Comment: @Symbol1 Since `\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node (A) {};` is the code essentially for `\tikzmark{A}`, can you expalin why moving the `tikzpicture` to before the *marks* fails to compile?

Comment: `remember picture` uses the aux file to store the coordinate of the origin of the picture relative to the paper. `tikzmark` uses the aux file to store the coordinates of each individual node.

Comment: @Symbol1 Thank you.  I failed to realize what I was skipping out on regarding `\tikzmark` when I was doing my own *cheat*.  If you can add a few details explain a `\tikzmark` approach that allows you to draw the background before the content is actually processed such that a twice-through run will properly compile, I'd accept your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`blend mode=darken` and `blend mode=multiply` actually do the trick

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

Hello world
\tikz[remember picture] \coordinate (A);%
Hello world
\tikz[remember picture] \coordinate (B);%
Hello world

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \coordinate (nA) at ([yshift=14pt]A);
    \coordinate (sB) at ([yshift=-14pt]B);
    \draw[fill=orange,blend mode=darken] (nA) rectangle (sB);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Another approach using `tikzmark`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \coordinate (nA) at ([yshift=14pt]pic cs:A);
    \coordinate (sB) at ([yshift=-14pt]pic cs:B);
    \draw[fill=orange] (nA) rectangle (sB);
\end{tikzpicture}

Hello world
\tikzmark{A}
Hello world
\tikzmark{B}
Hello world

\end{document}
```

### Why `tikzmark` is (sort-of) necessary in this case?

`remember picture` is implemented by
remembering in the aux file
the position of the current `tikzpicture`
relative to the current page.
Each `tikzpicture` will correspond to a line that looks like

> ```
> \pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid29}{21177794}{4593314}
> ```

where `pgfid29` means this is the 29th `remember picture`.
The next two numbers are x, y coordinates in `sp`.

Whenever you try to access a node `(A)`,
Ti*k*Z needs three information

- the coordinate of `(A)`
- the position of the picture that contains `(A)`
- the position of the current picture

Without `tikzmark` the aux file only knows the last two bullet points.
And `tikzmark` puts the first bullet point into the aux file.

BTW: I don't like the interface of `tikzmark`.
And for those who wants to reimplement,
suggestion is to look at the aux file to see what's going on there.
And copy the idea.

Comment: Nice solution.  I hadn't thought of  `blend mode`.  However, I'm not sure this will render properly on other's printers.

Comment: I would like to remark that blend mode is part of the PDF standard so the printers are to blame. (My experience is that printer drivers are quite faithful in following the standard. The screen renderers, such as macOS Preview or PDF.js, are lazier.)